# Javascript - Convertir una cadena Timestamp a formato fecha humana

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

Tengo el siguiente dato:

```
Timestamp: 1481751645.455596
```

Deseo convertirlo al siguiente formato: Wed, 14 Dec 2016 21:40:45 GMT. He usado la siguiente web: http://www.epochconverter.com/ para poder verificar que el formato Timestamp que les muestro sea correcto y sí, sí es correcto. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes probar

```
var unix_date = 1481751645.455596;
var date = new Date(unix_date * 1000);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! funciona.